# FullCalendar dayClick event does not fire

Tags: fullcalendar

Using version 3.4.0 of FullCalendar
and Jquery 3.2.0

Event click works, but day click does not work in IE only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After googling this for over an hour, ripping out most my code I then updated jquery to 3.2.1

Looks like some fixes were made
https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues?q=is%3Aissue+milestone%3A3.2.1+is%3Aclosed

And all works now in IE.

Answer (score 1):

What fixed for me was removing `overflow-x: hidden` from the HTML element. Its a known issue: https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/3615